# Cognos needs to query oracle stored procedure and get back a result set

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, cognos

I am using a reporting engine (Cognos Framework manager) to model my oracle OLTP db for report generation. Usually this is a straightforward process of recreating the tables and relationships in cognos framework manager. We are using the oracle OLTP db, there is no seaprate Datamart just for cognos reporting.

Now...for some reports, the fields can not be obtained simply by querying tables...there is a complex logic involved. So for this purpose, I am creating a stored procedure that will perform the logic. I was hoping that cognos can directly execute the stored procedure and get the required resultset. But in an oracle stoerd procedure, it is not easy to get the result set. Can cognos handle this?  If not, what are some ways of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Stored Procedure Query Subjects in Framework Manager.

[Here are the steps.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_fm.8.4.1.doc/ug_fm_i_stored_procedure_query_subjects.html)

The procedure must be run in Framework Manager to get a description of the result set that the procedure may return.

Comment: I saw the link...but did not get much info because there are no samples. Can framework manager get back a complete result set from a SP? Not just one value.